# Removing query string parameter on programmatic login

Tags: php, wordpress

**Situation:** With a link on external site, a user can be redirect to a wordpress page where is present a payment form. This page is only accessible to logged-in users. So into the link there is a parameter (containing the Username of the specific User) that is used to do a programmatic login.

At the end of programmatic login code, I have implemented some code in order to remove the parameter from the query string and to do a redirect to the new address without the parameter for progammatic login.

**Problem:** The removal of the parameter does not always happen.

**CODE:** (It is dived into two functions)

URL Example: `http://www.example.com/?page_id=00&token=pippo`

1. Function to check if the parameter is present (If TRUE do the programmatic login)

   ```
   add_action('after_setup_theme', 'autologin', 2, 10);
   function autologin() {
       if(isset($_GET['token'])) { //autologin token is set
           $username = $_GET['token'];
           programmatic_login($username);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Function to execute the programmatic login and remove the parameter from query string

   ```
   function programmatic_login( $username ) {

       if(is_user_logged_in()) {
           $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
           if($username != $current_user->user_login) {
               wp_logout();
           }
           else {
               //Remove the "token" from the URL + redirect
               $url = home_url( add_query_arg( null, null ));
               $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
               parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_str);
               unset($parsed_str['token']);

               $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/?";

               $http_builded = $actual_link . http_build_query($parsed_str);
               // wp_redirect( $http_builded );
               header('Location: ' . $http_builded, true);
               exit();
               // die();
           }       
       }

       if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
           // Set the new User
           $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
           $user_id = $user->ID;

           wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $username );
           wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
           // $user = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $username ) );
           do_action( 'wp_login', $username );

           if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
               error_log(print_r( $user->get_error_message(), TRUE));
           }

           if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {

               if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                   // Remove the "token" from the URL + redirect
                   $url = home_url( add_query_arg( null, null ));
                   $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
                   parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_str);
                   unset($parsed_str['token']);

                   $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/?";

                   $http_builded = $actual_link . http_build_query($parsed_str);
                   // wp_redirect( $http_builded );
                   header('Location: ' . $http_builded, true);
                   exit();
                   // die();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**Result:** The login always is successful but sometimes this parameter is not removed. More rarely, not happens the redirect because I see that the prefilled fields of the form remain the old ones (When I switch from one user to another).

Is there someone that see some errors? or do you have any suggestions to get more specific message or to do that better?

**P.S.:** I need to do the redirect because it solves a problem with the wp_verify_nonce () on the form submit

Comment: _“I need to do the redirect because it solves a problem with the wp_verify_nonce () on the form submit”_ – what problem? Are you sure that this is not just a simple collision of parameter names? If the nonce check uses a parameter named `token` as well (dunno, might as well be the case), then simply giving your URL parameter a different name would perhaps be enough already.

Comment: first of all, you always need to `exit` or `die` after redirect. Let's fix that

Comment: @CBroe: the flow is: Do the programmatic login (remove "token"). Inside the form there is a filed containing the result of `wp_create_nonce()`. Once the submit of form is done, I check into the backend code the `$_POST[action]` and the `wp_verify_nonce('the nonce from form field')`. However, I'll try to verify your suggestion. Stay Tuned!

Comment: @karacsi_maci: code updated and tried. No change detected

Comment: The problem persist, I tried to verify the @CBroe suggestion, but is not it the problem

Comment: Is there no one who has to give me some advice?